# how to set RGB colors in Pymol

Tags: python, visualization, scientific-computing, pymol

Can I ask if Pymol allows users to set atom color by user defined value ?
for example, I want to color all atoms by their biochemical features, the feather is considered to be RGB value, say [R G B] is equals to [feature1 feature2 feature3], how can I 
do this in Pymol ?

In addtion, if I already color the atoms, can I get the color value ? I tried to use cmd.getcolor(), but the value it returns is not recognized as RGB color, is there any other 
function in Pymol I can call to get atom color ?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to pymolwiki page [Color](http://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Color) and [Set Color](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Set_Color).

First, define a set of colors using your features (remember to normalize your feature values to scale [0,1], or [0, 255]):

```
set_color mycol1, [feature1R, feature1G, feature1B]
set_color mycol2, [feature2R, feature2G, feature2B]
...
```

Then you can color the atoms using the customized colors:

```
# color all alpha Carbons to mycol1:
color mycol1, n. CA
# color all backbone Nitrogens to mycol2:
color mycol1, n. N
```

To get atom color, refer to "[Getting Atom Colors](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Color#Getting_Atom_Colors)".
Suppose you have an atom named `youratom` and you want to get color for it:

```
atomcolor = []
iterate youratom, atomcolor.append(cmd.get_color_tuple(color))
print atomcolor[0]
```

`atomcolor[0]` is a tuple with RGB values in scale [0,1].